# Properties of $\Bbb{Q}/n\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

For $n$ a positive integer, let $\Bbb{Q}/n\Bbb{Z}$be the quotient of the group of rational numbers $\Bbb{Q} $ by the subgroup $n\Bbb{Z} $. For each of the following statements state whether it is true or false.
(a)every element of $\Bbb{Q}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is of finite order.
(b) There are only finitely many elements in $\Bbb{Q}/n\Bbb{Z}$ of any given finite order.
(c) Every proper subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is finite.
(d) $\Bbb{Q}/2\Bbb{Z}$and $\Bbb{Q}/5\Bbb{Z}$ are isomorphic as groups.
**Try**
(a) $\frac ab +n\Bbb{Z}$ be any element of $\Bbb{Q}/n\Bbb{Z}$.
Than $\frac ab +... +\frac ab (\text{adding nb times} ) =\frac {nab}b$ hence has finite order $nb$
(b) take $n>2$ and $n$ be a fixed prime. Then the element $\frac pn$ where $p$ is any prime, has order $n^2$ but there are infinitely many primes hence infinitely many such elements possible.
I am unable to proceed the other two options.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: (d) $\mathbb Q/2\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q/5\mathbb Z:a\mapsto \frac52a$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Kenta S are my explanations for (a) and (b) correct?(+1)for the hint

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: No, your answer to (b) is wrong.

Comment: Suppose $n=3$ then the elements $\frac 53,\frac 73,\frac {11}3,\frac {13}3...$ are distinct. Am I wrong?

Comment: $5/3$ and $23/3$ are equal modulo $3{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Thanks @Derek Holt Got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q/n\mathbb Z:a\mapsto n\cdot a$ is an isomorphism, so we only need to consider the case when $n=1$ in these questions. (this also immediately answers (d).)

**HINTS:**

(b) Your approach is on the right track, you should say the elements of order $d$ can be expressed as $m/d$ for some integer $m$, so...

(c) This is not true. Let $A=\{m/2^k:m,k\in\mathbb Z\}\subseteq\mathbb Q$ and consider $A/\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ (i.e., the group of elements with denominator a power of $2$.)

Comment: In option (b) the integer $m$ can be any integer but when reduced modulo $d$ then $\frac md$ will be any one of $\frac 1d,\frac 2d,...,\frac {d-1}d$.Hence there are finitely many such elements. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, that allows you to say there are *at most* $d$ such elements. Realize that it's not exactly $d$, since for example $2/4$ certainly doesn't have order $4$.